# Обработка звонков для планшетов с сим-картой

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, такая проблема - есть приложение которое обрабатывает исходящие вызовы, как результат гугл плей говорит всем планшетам что они не поддержуются, но на моем Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 сим-карта есть, но это ему не помогает, Google Play говорит что манифест приложения не разрешает.
Поэтому обращаюсь к вам, как убрать это и разрешить всем устройствам загружать мое приложение, должен ведь быть какой то вариант, вот Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="a.b.c"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:name=".YourAppClass"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InformationActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ReviewActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SearchReviewActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AdminActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".IntroActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RecodTableActivity" />

        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">

            <intent-filter>      
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажите в манифесте, что телефония не является обязательной для устройства:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как проверить есть ли слот для сим карты в устройстве? Т.е. не невставлена ли симкарта, а именно наличия возможности вставить симкарту.

Comment: @NikolayKolomiytsev, попробуйте как-то так https://ideone.com/cvO4Z7. Но я не знаю, что получится, учитывая, что на планшете со слотом для карты телефония считается отключенной.